# react-native button title is not visible

Tags: react-native, button

The color of the button text and the button background seems to be the same, so the title is not appearing!

Below is the code:

```
<Button title="No" style={styles.yesButtonStyle} onPress={this.abc} />
```

And the style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    yesButtonStyle : {
      backgroundColor: Constants.lightGreen,
      height: "12%",
      width:"30%" 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of button title text using css property:

> `color: white;`

Comment: It didn't help!

Comment: Can you please share the html source code that you get from the browser. Maybe the width and height is too small to display the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass color as a prop like

```
<Button 
  title="No" 
  color="#000000" 
  style={styles.yesButtonStyle} 
  onPress={this.abc} />
```